# Php: How to do a var_dump() in the syslog()?

Tags: php, debugging, logging, syslog

I'm debugging some php code of an API, and for this I'm using syslog() to view my debug messages. The problem is that I want to get some usefull logs. For example, is something null or false? Normally I use var_dump() for this, but since I'm working with in an API, var_dump, f*%$s up the API output.

I tried doing `syslog(LOG_ERR, var_dump($myVar));`, but to no avail.

Does anybody know how I can "pretty print" variables/arrays in the syslog?

Answer (score 10):

`var_dump()` does direct output. There's no provision for it to RETURN its formatted output, so you'll need to use output buffering:

```
ob_start();
var_dump($something);
syslog(LOG_ERROR, ob_get_clean());
```

Note that `print_r()` does have an optional 2nd argument to force it to return instead of outputting:

```
syslog(LOG_ERROR, print_r($something, TRUE));
```

Comment: it's LOG_ERR instead of LOG_ERROR

Answer (score 2):

`var_export()` and `print_r()` may return the contents instead of echoing it out

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the syslog primarily as a means to debug, instead of using `var_dump`,
 why dont you just 'tail' the syslog by using

`tail -f /var/log/syslog`

You can `grep` for any keyword by using

`tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep MY_KEYWORD --line-buffered`